# Using Object key as array index, Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array given by another developer, I am attaching screenshot for it.

[image]

Here the developer has used Object key as the array index. Now the console.log shows Array(0), and I cant stringify it. Because it gives me **[]** in the console.log.

How can I stringify this type of array.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could convert it to a normal object.

```
let o = Object.assign({}, ArrayVar);
```

You can use the resulting object however you see fit.

---

You can also convert the array into an array of objects.

```
let newArray = Object.keys(ArrayVar).map(k => {
    return {
        [k]: ArrayVar[k] // ECMA6 Syntax 
    };
});
```